# Does Jenkins support multiple timezones

Tags: jenkins, timezone

My Jenkins server hosted US and uses by the users in different time-zones.
we **don't** cross uses the project by different teams in different timezones (projects uses by the team in timezone-`A` does not uses by the team in  timezone-`B`).

it is annoying to convert project triggered time, notification time-stamps etc.. to each teams local time by mind each time.

is there any solution for this from Jenkins world other than hosting different servers?

Answer (score 1):

The [Jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Change+time+zone) only mentions forcing jelly embedded server to use a given time zone for formatting time stamps. Also [seen in this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/718310/783)

But that would not solve the build parameters issue, especially when *multiple* user timezones are involved.
For that, you have the (resolved) issue [JENKINS-9283](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9283) which adds the [timezone to cron syntax](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/compare/5540e93f4a10...73e151f3d158).

```
TZ=Europe/London
# This job needs to be run in the morning, London time
H 8 * * *
# BTW, nobody works at 5 o'clock, so we can run the test again
H(0-30) 15 * * *
```

From [JENKINS-43228](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43228), this seems effective only in 2.54.